# WebClient DownloadString with TextChanged Event C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webclient, downloadstring

I have an trouble in **C#** program which using **php** scripts to translate words and download the result string into `TextBox`.

My program has two TextBoxes

`txtWord`, `txtTranslatedWord`

and that's the simplified code

```
WebClient c = new WebClient();
private void txtWord_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string response = c.DownloadString("http://example.com/Services/Translator/lang/EnglishToArabic.php?Word=" + txtWord.Text);
    switch (response.ToLower())
    {
        case "not exist":
            {
                txtTranslatedWord.Text = "{Sorry but no translation for this word!}";
                break;
            }
        default:
            {
                txtTranslatedWord.Text = response;
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

The problem its when the text is changed the program lagging and looks like it would **Stopped Working**.

The program worked successfully but after so much **lagging** ,
especially if the writer is writing so fast.

I tried `BackgroundWorker` and make an delay like when user stop writing for 2 second then program start to translate but still lagging without any luck.

Is there any easy way to do this without problems?

Comment: I am confused , are you trying to convert 'php' code into 'c#'?

Comment: Sorry for the delay
the answer is yes

Comment: Is it WinForms?

Comment: yup its WinForms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use asynchrony.

`WebClient` does not support concurrent I/O operations, so will be use `HttpClient`.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

private async void txtWord_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var response = await client.GetStringAsync(
        "http://example.com/Services/Translator/lang/EnglishToArabic.php?Word=" + txtWord.Text);
    switch (response.ToLower())
    {
        case "not exist":
            {
                txtTranslatedWord.Text = "{Sorry but no translation for this word!}";
                break;
            }
        default:
            {
                txtTranslatedWord.Text = response;
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solves half the problem - the gui responsiveness issue.  What it doesn't account for is that you don't want to make your web call after every character the user types - you want to predict when they have finished typing.  This solution can actually return indeterminate results - it is possible for a call for a partial word to complete after one for the whole word.

Comment: I know that already and that's the reason why i said (simplified code)
i was only want any way to GetData fast without lag but thanks for your ideas ^^

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that every character your user types into the textbox results in a WebClient download that has to complete before the next keypress can be accepted.  I'd suggest you do the following...

Create a timer that starts or restarts each time the user enters a character and that when expires disables the textbox and runs the search before re-enabling the textbox.  You'd also do well to use an asynchronous WebClient call.

Comment: I already did that except async but i want any way to stop only lagging like BackgroundWorker but i got an exception when i do that i mean i don't want user to feel what's happens in the program like downloading or any...so if you have an solution code can you post an example?